# Laravel Manual Pagination Error

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I have a issue related to Laravel5 Manual Pagination.
I need to process an array of query builder result and some other arrays and make a pagination for that.

controller.

```
  public function searchCategory($id){
    $arr = DB::table('business_businesscatagories')->lists('fk_business_id');
    return Paginator::make($arr, count($arr), 2);
}
```

Namespaces..

```
 use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
```

But I got the error like below..

```
 FatalErrorException in IndexController.php line 122:
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::make()
```

How can I solve this issue....

Comment: Have you tried this return `\Paginator::make($arr, count($arr), 2);` probably namespace issue

Comment: Do you have that method `make` within your `LengthAwarePaginator` file

Comment: @Digitlimit, throwing Class 'Paginator' not found

Comment: Yeah I think the make method doesn't exist in LengthAwarePage

Comment: @Digitlimit, is there any way solve this issue.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I examined `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` and was able to confirm that it doesn't have `make` method.

However you can achieve this by using its constructor method.

```
__construct(mixed $items, int $perPage, int|null $currentPage = null, array $options = array())
```

Since you already have the correct namespace specified:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
```

You could simply do this:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($items, $total, $per_page);
```